# Moq - Setup mocked object using Generic functions for a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq, dry

In an attempt to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle in my unit tests I am trying to create a generic unit test that will perform the same test on several methods that all return an object which share the same interface.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to create a mock.Setup for the methods in the generic method.  Examples are as follows:

Here are the class Implementations:

```
public class RootClass
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Bar1 Method1(int x)
    {
        var bar = new Bar1();
        // do stuff //
        return bar;
    }
    public Bar2 Method2(string str)
    {
        var bar = new Bar2();
        // do stuff //
        return bar;
    }
}

public interface IBar
{
    string Message { get; set; }
    bool Success { get; set; }
    Exception ex { get; set; }
}

public class Bar1 : IBar
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public Exception ex { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class Bar2 : IBar
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public Exception ex { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the test implementations:

```
private static RootClass systemUnderTest;
private static Mock<IFoo> FooMock;

[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    FooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    systemUnderTest = new RootClass();
    systemUnderTest.Foo = FooMock.Object;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Method1_Bar1SuccessIsTrue()
{
    //FooMock.Setup(x => x.Method1(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Bar1);    <~~~~This is the Moq Setup I would like to move into the generic method
    AssertBarSuccessIsTrue<int, Bar1>(systemUnderTest.Bar1, FooMock.Object.Bar1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Method2_Bar2SuccessIsTrue()
{
    //FooMock.Setup(x => x.Method2(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new Bar2);
    AssertBarSuccessIsTrue<string, Bar2>(systemUnderTest.Bar2, FooMock.Object.Bar2)
}

private void AssertBarSuccessIsTrue<PARAM, BAR>(Func<PARAM, BAR> f, Func<PARAM, IBAR> task) where BAR : IBAR where PARAM : new()
{
    FooMock.Setup(x => task);  <~~~Throws an ArgumentException; no doubt because of the missing lambda expression.
    PARAM parameter = new PARAM();
    BAR bar = f.Invoke(parameter);
    Assert.IsTrue(bar.Success);
}
```

I have tried to make this work through several attempts including creating an argument for the lambda expression, creating an argument for the It.IsAny<>() expression, creating delegates for the specified method under test.  However, every attempt either creates a compiler error or throws a runtime exception.

I can create the generic test if I do a setup in every test (as seen in the commented out .Setup lines).  However does anyone have an idea how I can move that setup line into the generic method?  I know its only one line, but it seem to me this should be possible.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? The implementation of the methods for the IBar interface on the various Bars?

Comment: Full disclaimer -- Still not sure what you're doing but I would suggest Using a generic type constraint to get the actual type. ex.private void AssertBarSuccessIsTrue<PARAM, T>(Func<PARAM, T> f, Func<PARAM, T> task) where T : IBar

Comment: I think you are not repeating anything so that possibly it makes you worry.  In each test, you are setting-up different methods and of course with different arguments. Don't obsessively misuse DRY. What if tomorrow the whole signature of `Method1` or `Method2` changes; your complete effort toward DRY would be in vain though.

Comment: To add to @Alireza's comment, DRY is only one of many principles you should apply to your code. It isn't a rule that must be religiously following ad absurdum. Another very important (in fact, I'd suggest more important) principle is readability. You risk making your test code very complex and difficult to read simply to avoid a small amount of repetition.

Comment: I'd also agree with others' comments here that it is really unclear what you are trying to achieve. I can't see any need for the mock at all. Just apply tests to `Foo`.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity.  The code is an obfuscation and simplification of actual code.  The test implementation in question is meant to test a series of responses from a web service.  FooMock is a mock of the data layer, and RootClass the business layer.  All responses are interfaced by IBar.  The systems tested are business layer methods, which I can see is not clear from this code. The ultimate purpose is to find a way to move that setup method into a generic method; I have run into many unit test opportunities where having a generic setup method would be quite useful.